# Manually triggering Switchery switch - Doesn't work on Phonegap/Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, checkbox

I am using S[witchery JQuery plugin](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) for my Phonegap app switches. When I load a view, I am reading the switches settings (true or false) from `window.localStorage` (use it to persist / save the switches settings).

When the view is loaded, I ran a code that reads the data from the local storage for each switch and use the following code (an example) to switch it on if needed:

```
$(".switchery:nth(1)").click();
```

This will turn on the second switch.

**The problem:**

It works great on iOS7 but not on Android. When triggering the click on Android (tested on 2.3.6), it just stays the same. I also tried `.trigger('click')` with no success.

My goal is to populate the correct switches (on or off) using the data persistent in local storage, so the switches will be set to "on" or "off". By default they are "off" when rendered in the view.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to store all the switches in an array during initialization

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
elems.forEach(function(html) {
    switchery[html.getAttribute('id')] = new Switchery(html);
});
```

and create a local function to toggle switch like this

```
toggleSwitchery(id)
{
    var s = switchery[id];
    s.setPosition(true);
    s.handleOnchange(true);
}
```

This worked for me. In case you face any UI issue i.e. switch moves some extra pixels then open switchery.js and replace *jack.offsetWidth* by 30 in *Switchery.prototype.setPosition* function